# c# make debugger/cmd.exe close when pressing key

Tags: c#

Hi I am making a text adventure game in c#.
When I start the game I would like it to show a question if the user wants to either start the game or quit it.
This is what I started with.

```
`Console.WriteLine("Press Space to start the game!");
Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to quit the game!");
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Space)
{
    "My whole code of the game here"
}
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Don't know what to put here
 }`
```

I have not found a way to just make the application (the cmd.exe running the code) to just close. I found one way that is crashes but it still gets the windows warning message "has stopped working".
I found people answering this but none of the things I have tested works, some of these are:

```
`Environment.Exit(0)

Environment.Exit

Application.Exit

this.Close();

return;`
```

And either nothing happens or I get the message "has stopped working".

I am asking for a command for some way to close the game in this way.
And if somebody has a better solution to answering question with keys I would be happy for it as well instead of this that I am using

```
`if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Space)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a while loop with a boolean flag and put all logic there and in each iteration, scan the pressed key, if it is Escape then make the while loop flag false else continue.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Press Space to start the game!");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to quit the game!");

 bool isGameClose = false;
        while (!isGameClose)
        {
            ConsoleKey pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if(pressedKey == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game is On");
            }
            else if(pressedKey == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                isGameClose = true;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Game Exited!");
```

Comment: Thank you this works but since I am using Ctrl + f5 not only f5 is there any way to skip the "press any key to continue". And make it quit just as you press the key.